# Open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ written as the union of $U \times V$ each open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose I've got a set $Q \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$, which is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ (in terms of open balls).

I wish to prove that there exist sets $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A}$ and $\{ V_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in A}$, where $U_{\alpha} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $V_{\alpha} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ for all $\alpha \in A$, such that:

$Q = \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in A} [U_{\alpha} \times V_{\alpha}]$

I guess my biggest confusion is how to begin this proof. I am guessing that I need to first state that $Q$ can be written as a union of such cartesian products, and THEN I have to prove that the constituent sets are all open. But how would I start this proof?

EDIT: As far as this proof is concerned I'm allowed to say that $\mathbb{R}^{n+m} = \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$.

Comment: Start on $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m$ then move to $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$. Think about the projection mapping $X \times Y \to X$ where $X$ and $Y$ are general topological spaces.

Comment: HINT: show that any open ball contains a small rectangle with the same center.

Comment: Okay, so if I say that $Q \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$, does this automatically mean I can say that $Q = \bigcup_{\alpha \in A}U_{\alpha} \times V_{\alpha}$ for some sets $U_{\alpha} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $V_{\alpha} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m}$? Then I just need to prove that each of these sets is open?

Comment: What they are hinting at is that if $Q$ is open, you can write it as the union of open balls in $R^{n+m}$. Each of these open balls has an open rectangle transcribed within in it, and the projection of these rectangles onto the spaces $R^n$ and $R^m$ are...

Comment: Not exaclty. Do you know about open maps?

Comment: Oh I see. Since $Q$ is open, we can write $Q = \bigcup_{q \in Q} B_{r_{q}}(q)$ for $\{ r_{q} \}_{q \in Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{+}$. Then prove that for each $q$, there exists an open rectangle $U_{q} \times V_{q} \subseteq B_{r_{q}}(q)$, and so $Q = \bigcup_{q \in Q} U_{q} \times V_{q}$ ?

Comment: I do not know about open maps, I'm not well-versed in topology. This proof just came up in my study of differential geometry so I really only understand this in the context of open balls.

Comment: My mistake, I was thinking about a similar problem involving the projection mapping. What you are trying to prove is the definition of the product topology! So what you want is to prove that the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$, induced by the standard metric, is the product topology $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m$. Now sure how to help you without general topology though.

Comment: Yes exactly, I am trying to prove that the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$ coincides with the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{m} \cong \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$!